# How can I sync ftp server with my local computer via cronjob or other means

Tags: linux, sync, ftp

Right now I am operating on a webserver which gets files pushed to it every few hours while I am working. I have to check each file that I upload has a different timestamp than when I had started working on it (which can be an issue). Is there a program or script that can automatically download all new files from the webserver and update my files before I start working on them? The only things I have been able to find so far are for syncing the files I have locally to the server, which I have no issues with. I am running linux on my work computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to mirror directories where newer date stamps get precedence. I use `lftp`'s `mirror` command in a similar context, which is scriptable.

You will still have problems if you mirror before starting to work on a file, edits it, and then finds that someone has uploaded a new version during this time. What you most probably need in circumstances like these is version control, specifically **distributed** version control, such as [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/).